# How could I find fantasy stories with all female characters?

Tags: online-resources, female-characters

I would be interested in reading a fantasy novel with all-female characters. Is there a good resource for finding such stories? (Or more generally any written science fiction or fantasy with all-female characters.)

(Background: a few years back, I saw a movie with only women were in it. I thought to myself there might be a fantasy novel or a short story where all the characters are women. Can you help me find one?)

Please don't just post your favorite story here — ideally, do you know of a way for me to search stories based on this criterion (having only female characters)?

Comment: It isn't only women, but [The Mists of Avalon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mists_of_Avalon) retells the King Arthur story from the female character's perspective.

Comment: I have voted to reopen, as this is the exact equivalent of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-there-any-science-fiction-stories-without-humans-at-all.

Comment: Why close so fast and not ask to edit the question if it i not clear?

Comment: He felt this question wasn't salvageable. Even if reworded into a real question, it'll be a list question that is a lot like another list question that was closed. A triple whammy.

Comment: @Dampe. I'm having a hard time understanding the rationale behind the closing also. It's pretty clear from the meta discussion that "recommendation" type questions are ok, and that's essentially what's being asked here. Yes it could maybe use a bit of rewording and clarification, but, like Martha, I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: I am not looking for a list of novels I am simply looking for a fantasy novel or a short story that all characters are female only. Does such a story exist? I'm recollecting that there was a movie done that all characters were played by women, hence my question about a book.

Comment: @shadowfission: Zypher likes to swoop down and close things from time to time. I was just saying why he did it. Vote reopen. You have THA POWA!!!

Comment: This question is off topic, as per [this answer in meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/351#351). Zypher was quite correct to close this. If it's reopened, I'll vote to close. Again.

Comment: @neilfein What would make this question to be on topic then?

Comment: Sorry, but as long as it's a recommendation question (and as long as the community decides to not allow them), it's simply off-topic. It needs to be a question that has a clear, single answer. Unfortunately, most of the questions on this site are mediocre and create the impression that unclear questions are okay here.

Comment: In other words if I were to say that I have read such a story but I cannot remember the author nor the title, can someone help  identifying this, would be considered not off topic? And I am not asking for recommendation simply stating a story that meets the requirements. I am trying to be as specific as I can.

Comment: @Darius: That would not be [honest](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) of you. The latest trend on [Meta SFF.SE](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/351#351) is against this kind of list question (whether it's formulated as a recommendation or not).

Comment: That is why I did not formulated it like that. Anyhow, I better go back to work....

Comment: @neilfein I think the real issue is that the meta post you pointed at didn't exist until yesterday, and before that, the overwhelming consensus was in the other direction [link](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26/are-recommend-me-questions-allowed). That being said, according to the most recent info, I agree, the question isn't on topic. The real problem here is that a mod suddenly swooped in and acted against community consensus without making any effort to fix the consensus first.

Comment: @Darius - I'm sorry, but in [What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic) it was decided by the community that all recommendations questions are off-topic.  I believe this is because it is difficult to choose a single correct answer, and because these questions encourage a never-ending stream of answers.

Comment: @Mark Rogers - I understand but I also think that people will be still asking those kind of questions.

Comment: @Darius - I agree, the volume of such questions may influence people's opinion on the matter.

Comment: @Darius: As an experiment, I tried asking your question in a completely different way. **I do not intend to make a habit of this.** Feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it. But note that [it is likely that the original question would be deleted](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/411/culling-list-and-recommendation-questions). See also [my answer about this question on that Meta thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/411/culling-list-and-recommendation-questions/430#430).

Comment: @Gilles - I like this approach. Let's see if this works. Nice one.

Comment: The anthology *Chicks in Chainmail* and its sequels (with equally groan-worthy names) feature fantasy stories that mess with traditional gender roles in a variety of ways. Some of them have a majority female characters.

Comment: Poul Anderson's [Virgin Planet](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?53366) comes close, *almost* all of the characters are female.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found a website that possibly solves this problem of mine. It would the closest I can find.

[Women-Only Worlds](http://feministsf.org/bibs/womenonlyworld.html)

Comment: Great find! This list only answers part of your question though :/ It's limited to societies/worlds, but misses out on other story scenarios focused on women casts.

Comment: Hence my comment that it is the closest to what I was able to find and I'm still looking for that "Chicks in Chainmail" anthology....

Answer (score 4):

TV Tropes is always well updated, they have a long list of women-only worlds here http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LadyLand.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with a site or resource where you can find only female protagonist stories, but JF Rivkin's Silverglass Quartet features mainly female characters (or, at least, mainly female powerful characters), as does the Sword and Sorceress series of books edited by Marion Zimmer Bradley.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small list [here](http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/Female_characters_in_SFF). If that wiki were better maintained, it would be more helpful.